# Linq quote returns no items if column of char(2) has default value of two spaces

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have a `ProdFinSize` table that has `Range`, `Color`, `Model`, `Scale`, `Size`, `Rise`, `Inseam` columns on it and the data type for the `Inseam` column is `char(2)` and has a default value of two spaces.

I wrote this SQL query to test the results I wanted.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProdFinSize
WHERE Range = '020' 
  and Color = '05' 
  and Model = 'JU' 
  and Scale = '1' 
  and Size = '34' 
  and Rise = 'R' 
  and inseam = '';
```

When I execute this, it returns a single item as it should.

Next I implemented the same thing using LINQ to Entities in an ASP.NET WebAPI

Here is my api function call

```
// GET /api/inventory/stockcheck
[Route("CheckStock")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult CheckStock(string range, string color, string model, string scale,
                                                 string size, string rise, string inseam = "")
{
    try
    {
        ProdFinSize product = null;                       
        product = berle.ProdFinSizes.Single(
            item =>
            item.Range == range &&
            item.Color == color &&
            item.Model == model &&
            item.Scale == scale &&
            item.Size == size &&                        
            item.Rise == rise &&
            item.Inseam == inseam
        );          

        // check if we found a matching product
        if (product != null)
        {                 
            // see if the item is in-stock
            var available = (product.FinSzOnHand-product.FinSzAloc-product.FinSzRlsd) > 0;
            return Ok(available.ToString());
        }
            return Ok("False");
        }           
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e.Message);
            //return Ok("Item not found");
         }
     }
```

Now when I make the api call and pass the same values that I used in the SQL query, it returns a message: `Sequence Contains No Elements`.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing and why the same query in LINQ to Entities does not return the single result, as it should?

I'm new to LINQ to Entities, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Note I do not have the ability to change any of the columns or column data types on the database table.

When I run SQL Profiler, the query below gets executed.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[CompanyCode] AS [CompanyCode], 
    [Extent1].[Range] AS [Range], 
    [Extent1].[Color] AS [Color], 
    [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Extent1].[Scale] AS [Scale], 
    [Extent1].[Inseam] AS [Inseam], 
    [Extent1].[Size] AS [Size], 
    [Extent1].[Rise] AS [Rise], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzProd] AS [FinSzProd], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzOnHand] AS [FinSzOnHand], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzXfrIn] AS [FinSzXfrIn], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzXfrOut] AS [FinSzXfrOut], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzRetn] AS [FinSzRetn], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzShip] AS [FinSzShip], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzRsrvd] AS [FinSzRsrvd], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzRlsd] AS [FinSzRlsd], 
    [Extent1].[FinSzAloc] AS [FinSzAloc], 
    [Extent1].[DateTimeStamp] AS [DateTimeStamp], 
    [Extent1].[FormID] AS [FormID], 
    [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    [Extent1].[rowguid] AS [rowguid]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [ProdFinSize].[CompanyCode] AS [CompanyCode], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Range] AS [Range], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Color] AS [Color], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Scale] AS [Scale], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Inseam] AS [Inseam], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Size] AS [Size], 
    [ProdFinSize].[Rise] AS [Rise], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzProd] AS [FinSzProd], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzOnHand] AS [FinSzOnHand], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzXfrIn] AS [FinSzXfrIn], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzXfrOut] AS [FinSzXfrOut], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzRetn] AS [FinSzRetn], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzShip] AS [FinSzShip], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzRsrvd] AS [FinSzRsrvd], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzRlsd] AS [FinSzRlsd], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FinSzAloc] AS [FinSzAloc], 
    [ProdFinSize].[DateTimeStamp] AS [DateTimeStamp], 
    [ProdFinSize].[FormID] AS [FormID], 
    [ProdFinSize].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    [ProdFinSize].[rowguid] AS [rowguid]
    FROM [dbo].[ProdFinSize] AS [ProdFinSize]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Range] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Color] = @p__linq__1) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Model] = @p__linq__2) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Scale] = @p__linq__3) AND (@p__linq__3 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Size] = @p__linq__4) AND (@p__linq__4 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Rise] = @p__linq__5) AND (@p__linq__5 IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Inseam] = @p__linq__6) AND (@p__linq__6 IS NOT NULL)',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000),@p__linq__1 varchar(8000),@p__linq__2 varchar(8000),@p__linq__3 varchar(8000),@p__linq__4 varchar(8000),@p__linq__5 varchar(8000),@p__linq__6 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='020',@p__linq__1='05',@p__linq__2='JU',@p__linq__3='1',@p__linq__4='34',@p__linq__5='R',@p__linq__6=NULL
```

Comment: [Run the Sql Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx) to see exactly what query is being executed.

Comment: one comment...  DB's are normally case insensitive..  are you sure you don't have a simple case issue here?

Comment: You may want to call .Trim() on columns of type char to make sure you're not comparing padded strings.

Comment: maybe you should post the data too...  there is something simple not matching...

Comment: Or you might be able to [get the query from EF itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

Comment: The data is the same that is in the SQL query above. I also tried adding trim, with the same result. Sequence contains no elements.

Comment: Also the case is the same in the db.

Comment: Look at the ed of the SQL: you are passing the parameter assignment `@p__linq__6=NULL`. This conflicts with the condition `@p__linq__6 IS NOT NULL` in the `WHERE` clause. You could try changing the default value of the 'inseam' parameter in your method call to `"  "` (two spaces).

Answer (score 0):

The default value of parameter `inseam` is "" instead of "  " (two space)